# Mongoose connection Db property is missing properties from Mongodb DB? Typescript error

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I have the following setup. Typescript and Node, and combination of Mongoose and [Typegoose](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose) for models. This is how I obtain my database

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Db } from "mongodb";
import config from "@/config";

export default async (): Promise<Db> => {
  const connection = await mongoose.connect(config.databaseUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  });
  return connection.connection.db;
};
```

And this is the error that I get

```
Type 'Db' is missing the following properties from type 'Db': readConcern, readPreference, bsonOptions, namespace, and 4 more.
```

Somewhere along the line of updating dependencies, this part got messed up, it's weird because connection.db is of type Mongodb.Db...

These are my versions

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@typegoose/typegoose": "8.3.0",
        "@types/mongodb": "3.6.5",
        "mongodb": "4.1.2",
        "mongoose": "5.13.8", 
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.11.0",
        "typescript": "4.1.3"
    }
```

Typegoose required me to use 5.13.8 version (while i previously used 5.12 something) and this seems to broke everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this issue was also brought up on the discord and discussed there, the answer was:*

In the project `mongodb@4.1.x` was installed, where as `mongoose@5.13.x` only supports (and uses) `mongodb@3.6.x` (and `@ŧypes/mongodb@3.6.x`) and so the types were incompatible.